# $T: V \rightarrow W$ is surjective. Show there exists a right inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra

Informally, I believe, the proof would be like this: Since the preimage of each element of $W$ is nonempty, we can choose an element from each preimage to be in the image of the right inverse. Since the right inverse $S$ should be a linear map it suffices to do so for the elements of the basis of $W$. Then $TSw = w$ for all $w \in W$.

How would I make this proof formal and rigorous? How do I formally "use" the axiom of choice? And is it necessary to pick a basis for $W$ as I did to complete the proof?

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct strategy here. What you've written is almost a complete solution already.

Pick a basis $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ for $W$. For each $w_i$, there exists a $v_i \in V$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$. Now define a linear map $S:W\to V$ by setting $S(w_i)=v_i$ and extending linearly; that is, $S(a_1 w_1 +\ldots +a_n w_n) = a_1 v_1 +\ldots +a_n v_n$. This is a well-defined linear map, and it is a right inverse for $T$.

I don't think it's necessary to worry about where the axiom of choice is used here, but yes, you do need to pick a basis for $W$.

Comment: The axiom of choice is explicitly used when you assume that every vector space has a basis. This, however, is a standard assumption.

Comment: You've assumed that $W$ is finite dimensional

Comment: I suppose I have, but really only notationally. Changing $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ to $\{w_i\}_{i\in I}$ yields the correct argument

Comment: Okay, and if you don't assume finite dimensionality, then wouldn't you have to mention the axiom of choice in the proof?

Comment: As @Omnomnomnom mentioned, the axiom of choice is necessary to prove that every vector space (finite dimensional or not) has a basis. After that, you don't have to directly invoke it.